# ruby on rails bootsy image upload not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby on rails, and I'm trying to add a WYSIWYG editor to my website. I have installed bootsy following the instructions on https://github.com/volmer/bootsy. It is giving me this error whenever I try to upload an image: [Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KrWq.png)

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see bootsy's [readme requirements](https://github.com/volmer/bootsy#requirements), you will notice the following:

> ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick (for MiniMagick)

This means that to run the plugin you will need ImageMagick installed on your local machine. This is very easy to do.

If you are on Mac:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

For the other operating systems, you can read more on [ImageMagick's official website](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php).

Comment: i'm on windows - I've installed imagemagick and graphicsmagic and verified that they work... still no luck. restarted the server, nothing :/

Comment: In that case, can you provide the logs from the server where you upload the file but you get the error? When debugging, that would be the rule of thumb - see logs and errors.

Comment: Ok now this is really weird - I cloned a fresh copy of my RoR app from github without bootsy and reinstalled it, and it works now. no clue what happened.